# Override _colors.less in backend

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides, backend, less

I need to override _colors.less to change color on admin backend.

The file is here : **vendo/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/source/variables/_colors.less**

I don't find solution to do it, I need to make it in custom module, to separate the core from custom.

Comment: hello ! did you find a solution ? I'm trying to do the same